# Add event to wpf controller when a property value changes

Tags: c#, wpf, tabcontrol

I have a property

```
public sealed partial class Computer
{
    private bool _online;
    public bool Online
    {
        get { return _online; }
        set
        {
            _online = value;
            RaiseProperty("Online");
        }
    }
 }
```

Which raises an event of type INotifyPropertyChanged

```
public sealed partial class Computer : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
  public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private void RaiseProperty(string propertyName)
    {
        if (this.PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            this.PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
 }
```

My question is, how can I add an additional event telling in this case an TabControl to run a specific method each time the Online Property changes?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to register a method to the `PropertyChanged` event

```
MyComputer.PropertyChanged += Computer_PropertyChanged;

void Computer_PropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.PropertyName == "Online")
    {
        // Do Work
    }
}
```

Comment: Gosh, that was embarrassingly simple :O

Comment: If you will use this solution, look at http://george.softumus.com/?p=32 - there is solution how to prevent using "magic-strings" (like "Online") in your code

Comment: @chopikadze Thanks, I'll have to take a closer look at his code someday. I never did like using "magic strings" in the PropertyChanged event.

Comment: Fixed link from above: http://george.softumus.com/2011/10/inotifypropertychanged-and-magic.html

Answer (score 1):

```
public sealed partial class Computer
{
    // This event is fired every time when Online is changed
    public event EventHandler OnlineChanged;

    private bool _online;
    public bool Online
    {
        get { return _online; }
        set
        {
            // Exit if online value isn't changed
            if (_online == value) return;

            _online = value;
            RaiseProperty("Online");

            // Raise additional event only if there are any subscribers
            if (OnlineChanged != null)
                OnlineChanged(this, null);
        }
    }
}
```

You can use this event like:

```
Computer MyComputer = new MyComputer();
MyComputer.OnlineChanged += MyComputer_OnlineChanged;

void MyComputer_OnlineChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Computer c = (Computer)c;
    MessageBox.Show("New value is " + c.Online.ToString());
}
```

Comment: Rachels solution was more spot on and was easily implemented. Though your idea was not bad :) Too bad only one of you can get the "accepted answer".

Comment: Rachel's solution is much more simpler and useful. My solution is better actually only when you should monitor the same property in a lot of places. If you want to monitor changes only in 1-2-3 places or you should monitor some properties - Rachel's is much more better.

Comment: It's only used one place, but's something to consider though.